# How to parse xml subtree in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hello have worten some php code to parse a xml file as long if i use seperate fields this works like a charm but how i can call a subtree ?

like eg :

````
<item>
  <items>
    <date>
      <from>2020-03-23</from>
      <until>2020-03-27</until>
    </date>
  </items>
</item>
```
````

Comment: can you add your code that you use so far as it is not clear on the methods / classes used. Also please try to clarify what you mean by `parse xml subtree` - what is the desired result / output etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume with subtree you mean an element within an element etc.

PHP offers a built in solution for this: [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string)

```
$xml = <<<BLOCK
<item>
  <items>
    <date>
      <from>2020-03-23</from>
      <until>2020-03-27</until>
    </date>
  </items>
</item>
BLOCK;

var_dump(simplexml_load_string($xml));
```

You can read a file directly aswell by using [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution for this problem i have done the following:

````
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$xml_file = simplexml_load_file("converted.xml");
echo $xml_file->date[0]->from;
echo $xml_file->date[0]->until;
?>


```
````